# Error while trying to extract text from pdf file using pdfminer.six

Tags: python, pdf, windows-10, pdfminer

I am trying to extract text from pdf using pdfminer.six library (like [here](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/highlevel.html#api-extract-text)), I have already installed it in my virtual environment. here is my code :

```
import pdfminer as miner

text = miner.high_level.extract_text('file.pdf')


print(text)
```

but when I execute the code with `python pdfreader.py` I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\pdfreader.py", line 9, in <module>
    text = miner.high_level.extract_text('pdfBulletins/corona1.pdf')
AttributeError: module 'pdfminer' has no attribute 'high_level'
```

I suspect it has something to do with the Python path, because I installed `pdfminer` inside my virtual environment, but I see that this installed `pdf2txt.py` outside in my system python install. Is this behavior normal? I mean something that happens inside my `venv` should not alter my system Python installation.

I successfully extracted the text using `pdf2txt.py` utility that comes with `pdfminer.six` library (from command line and using system python install), but not from the code inside my `venv` project. My `pdfminer.six` version is **20201018**

What could be the problem with my code ?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26495057/14316282

Comment: @RolvApneseth tried the code there, does not work, I am suspecting it has something to do with Python path, because I installed pdfminer inside my virtual environment, but I see that this installed pdf2txt.py outside in my system python install, is this behaviour normal ? I mean something that happens inside my venv should not alter my system python installation

Comment: That behaviour is certainly not normal. Are any other modules you installed installing on the system rather than in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 3):

*pdfminer high_level extract_text* requires additional parameters to work properly. This code below uses *pdfminer.six* and it extracts the text from my pdf files.

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

pdf_file = open('my_file.pdf', 'rb')
text = extract_text(pdf_file, password='', page_numbers=None, maxpages=0, caching=True, codec='utf-8', laparams=None)
print(text)
```

Here are a couple of additional posts that I wrote on extracting text from PDF files that might be useful:

- [Unsuccessful attempt to extract text data from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029574/unsuccessful-attempt-to-extract-text-data-from-pdf/61030757#61030757)
- [How to convert whole pdf to text in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55461041/how-to-convert-whole-pdf-to-text-in-python/55462141#55462141)
- [how to write code to extract a specific text and integer on the same line from a pdf file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231498/how-to-write-code-to-extract-a-specific-text-and-integer-on-the-same-line-from-a/58334118#58334118)
- [Python Data Extraction from an Encrypted PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226546/python-data-extraction-from-an-encrypted-pdf/58295892#58295892)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is trying to use a function from a module you have not imported. Importing `pdfminer` does NOT automatically also import `pdfminer.high_level`.

This works:

```py
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

text = extract_text('file.pdf')

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract texts (plain and containing PDF operators) from PDF document

Here is a sample code extracting all the above from all document pages.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""
try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install [`pdfminer.six`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer.six/) instead of just [`pdfminer`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/):

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

Only after that, you can import `extract_text` as:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Problem in my case

pdfminer and pdfminer.six are both installed,
`from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text` than tries to use the wrong package.

#### Solution

For me uninstalling pdfminer worked:

`pip uninstall pdfminer`

now you should only have pdfminer.six installed and should be able to import extract_text.